# Optimize JS file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I developed UI part. I used REACT JS. It works good. Attached code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { notification, Alert, Spin, Form, Input, Button, Typography } from 'antd';
import { usePromise } from 'innroad.common.ui';
import * as apiService from 'services/ApiService';
import { LAYOUT, TAIL_LAYOUT } from 'constants/layouts';
import styles from './AddTown.scss';

const AddTown = () => {
  const onFail = (error) => notification.error({ message: error });
  const [{ data, isLoading }, createNewTown] = usePromise(
    apiService.createTown,
    { initialData: [], onFail }
  );

  const handleFormFinish = (formValue) => createNewTown(formValue);

  return (
      <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
        <Typography.Title>Create New Town</Typography.Title>
        {data.length > 0 && (<Alert message={`New town id : ${data.join(',')}`} type="info" />)}
        <Form {...LAYOUT} onFinish={handleFormFinish}>
          <Form.Item
            name="name"
            label="Town Name :"
            rules={[{ whitespace: true, required: true, message: 'This is required field' }]}
          >
            <Input />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item {...TAIL_LAYOUT}>
            <Button htmlType="submit" className={styles.submitButton}>Submit</Button>
            <Button type="link" className="ant-btn"><Link to="/">Cancel</Link></Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Spin>
  );
};

export default AddTown;
```

After that, I had a code review. I said that here "Fragment is not needed here". He talked about this fragment (after **return**):

```
<>
  ...
</>
```

Could anyone explain to me, which line he means and why? As I understand we are talking about a big fragments where I added button and functionality. Or he means remove just this symbol. How need I change my code? One again, sorry for this question, but I'm new in JS.

Comment: If there is and only is one child inside the Fragment, it's not necessary (could be directly removed). Refer to the document of [React Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html) : A common pattern in React is for a component to return **multiple** elements

Comment: React components need only return a single node element and the `Spin` component serves that purpose, so the wrapping fragment is extraneous and unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

A React Fragment is this sort of thing:

```
<>
  JSX code goes here
</>
```

The `<>` and `</>` indicate the fragment's delimiters, similarly to how `<div>` and `</div>` indicates the delimiters of a `div`.

A JSX fragment is needed when you need to construct a single JavaScript expression from multiple adjacent JSX tags *without* a parent container of some sort. For example, the following is invalid:

```
const elms = (
  <div>foo</div>
  <div>bar</div>
);
```

because the top level of the JSX has more than one element on it.

For multiple elements on the top level, the syntax requires you to surround them in a JSX fragment:

```
const elms = (
  <>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div>bar</div>
  </>
);
```

But, in your code, the top level of what is returned from `AddTown` only contains *one* JSX tag, the `<Spin` component. So, the fragment delimiters `<>` and `</>` around `Spin` are not needed; they're just noise, and so can be removed.

Change your code to:

```
return (
    <Spin spinning={isLoading}>
        ...
    </Spin>
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code. I tried do it, but I get error in `<Spin spinning={isLoading}>`
**Expected indentation of 4 space characters but found 6.**. I tried delete space, but it doesn't help

Comment: That's just a linter warning - add or delete spaces until it verifies.